# Stretchy tree and system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, solution-verification, linear-programming, programming

A stretchy tree is here marked with bold edges:

[image]

Then I get the the system of equations here by matrix:
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\
\end{pmatrix} and

-b=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
-8\\
5\\
-6
\
\end{pmatrix}

A is with the rows a, b, c, d and the columns (b, c), (b, e), (d, e), (e, a).

I have to solve the system Ax=-b

So I think I got :
$A^{-1}$=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\
\end{pmatrix}
And then the solution
$A^{-1}(-b)$=\begin{pmatrix}
5\\
3\\
6\\
2
\
\end{pmatrix}
so $x_{bc}=5$,$x_{be}=3$, $x_{de}=6$,$x_{ea}=2$.

Is that correct or am I totally wrong?

Comment: I haven't a clue, I can't make heads or tails of what you've written.

Comment: I hope it is easier to find heads or tails in the problem now?

Comment: I don't know what a "stretchy tree" is. I don't know how the system of equations comes from the stretchy tree. I don't know what row $a$ means. That's strike three.

Comment: @para No, your problem is still totally unclear.  Please provide all relevant information. Also: You can accept answers to show that you appreciate the work of the people.

Comment: @callculus has a point there, para. You've gotten answers to seven questions you have posted, but you haven't accepted an answer to a single one. If you don't find any answers worth accepting, why do you keep asking questions here?